# Получение данных за прошлую неделю

Tags: mysql, sql

За прошлый месяц данные получаю так:

```
SELECT * 
FROM timesheet 
WHERE start > LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 2 MONTH  
    AND start < DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY)         
GROUP BY date
```

А вот как получать за прошлую неделю?

Comment: Отформатируйте и разбейте код на строки пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то подобное вам надо использовать

```
SELECT * 
FROM `timesheet` 
WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(NOW()) - WEEKOFYEAR(`date`) = 1 
      AND YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(NOW())
GROUP BY `date`
```

P.S. Возможно вместо `date` следует `start` использовать. Непонятно у вас по запросу.
P.P.S. Подозреваю для первой и последней недели года недочеты.

**UPD** Более продвинутый вариант

```
SELECT * 
FROM `timesheet` 
WHERE `date` BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY)
             AND 
                     (CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY - INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
GROUP BY `date`
```

Тут вычисляются точно даты начала и конца предыдущей недели относительно текущей недели.

Answer (score 0):

Нужные даты Понедельник и Воскресенье на прошлой неделе можно найти так:

```
SELECT 
  (CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) + 7) DAY) AS `monday`,
  (CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) + 1) DAY) AS `sunday`
```

Эти даты можно использовать в вашем запросе. Предполагаю, что поле start имеет тип DATE:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM 
  timesheet AS t,
  (SELECT 
     (CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) + 7) DAY) AS `monday`,
     (CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) + 1) DAY) AS `sunday`
  ) AS w
WHERE t.`start` BETWEEN w.`monday` AND w.`sunday`
```

Для типа DATETIME пришлось бы добавлять ко времени "до" 23 часа 59 минут.